# AddEventListener only being called the first time and doesn't work after

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am creating a mock website for a restaurant and in the header i am trying to create tabs that load js modules but i am only able to get it to work the first click and then it stops working. im fairly new and not sure what is causing the issue.

```
import { renderHomepage } from './homepage'
import { renderMenupage } from './menu'
import { renderContactpage } from './contact'

renderContactpage();

const content = document.querySelector('#content');
const homeTab = document.querySelector("#home");
const menuTab = document.querySelector('#menu');
const contactTab = document.querySelector('#contact');
const secondMenu = document.querySelector('#secondMenu');
console.log(menuTab);

const removeDOM = () => {
    content.innerHTML = ``;
}

homeTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeDOM();
    renderHomepage();
});

menuTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeDOM()
    renderMenupage()
});

contactTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeDOM()
    renderContactpage()
});

secondMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    removeDOM();
    renderMenupage();
});
```

please let me know if i need to give more information.

Comment: Well sounds like you are replacing content so you have new elements. Hard to guess without an example that shows the problem.

Comment: yes i am using inner html to replace the dom with the one of the new page. is there a way to show you an example

Comment: If you replace elements, you probably need to learn about event delegation.

Comment: ok thank you also would there be an easier way to create website tabbing.

Comment: Does `removeDOM` also remove the tabs? If so, alongside with it, your event listeners will be lost as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an event listener multiple times, that will cause it to fire once. To avoid this, try using `onclick`. For example, something like this should work:

```js
import { renderHomepage } from './homepage';
import { renderMenupage } from './menu';
import { renderContactpage } from './contact';

renderContactpage();

const content = document.querySelector('#content');
const homeTab = document.querySelector("#home");
const menuTab = document.querySelector('#menu');
const contactTab = document.querySelector('#contact');
const secondMenu = document.querySelector('#secondMenu');
console.log(menuTab);

const removeDOM = () => {
    content.innerHTML = '';
}

homeTab.onclick = () => {
    removeDOM();
    renderHomepage();
};

menuTab.onclick = () => {
    removeDOM()
    renderMenupage()
};

contactTab.onclick = () => {
    removeDOM()
    renderContactpage()
};

secondMenu.onclick = () => {
    removeDOM();
    renderMenupage();
};
```

**Hoped this helped!**